# How do I get a List of all the Service in Kubernetes using kubectl

Tags: kubectl

How do I get a List of all the Service in Kubernetes using kubectl

```
ks get services -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}. 
{.metadata.namespace}.svc.cluster.local{"\n"}{end}'


kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
telegraf.default.svc.cluster.local
influxdb.default.svc.cluster.local
mysql-instance-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
mysql-instance.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with `ks` but assume it's an alias or wrapper of `kubectl`.

You can get all namespaces using `--all-namespaces`.

So you should (haven't tried this) be able to:

```bash
FILTER='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}.{.metadata.namespace}.svc.cluster.local{"\n"}{end}'

kubectl get services \
--all-namespaces \
--output=jsonpath="${FILTER}"
```